# How to hide messages after certain time

Tags: magento2, javascript, messages

I want to **hide** `success` / `error` messages after 5 seconds once I have added items to the cart.

I have extended `messages.js` with the following code to hide the message after 5 seconds

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500);
}, 3000);
```

When I add item to the cart for the first time the message gets hidden after 5 seconds but when I add another item to the cart the message is not showing up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create **app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages': {
                'SR_MagentoStackExchange/js/view/messages-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

2. Create **app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            /**
             * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                var self = this;
                self.messages.subscribe(function(messages) {
                    if (messages.messages) {
                        if (messages.messages.length > 0) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                customerData.set('messages', {});
                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Clear browser js cache.

***Note: I have tested in 2.3 version.***

Comment: is this for all the messages? adding product to the basket, discount code

Comment: @SohelRana, If you have a time can you look at this thread similar to this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315736/increase-the-success-exception-message-time-span-in-magento-2

Comment: Hmm can't get this to work for some reason, the js is loading as it console logs but the timeout never happens. messages.messages returns empty array  

Answer (score 5):

You can use css.

```
.message.success {
    animation: css 0s 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes css {
    to {
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

path: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml

in your theme

app/design/frontend/Namespace/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(".message.success").fadeOut(3000); 

    //$(".message.success").delay(3000).slideUp(300);
    });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested this in Magento 2.4.4.

Copy this file to your theme:
`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml`

into this folder of your theme:
`Magento_Theme/templates/messages.phtml`

Also, copy the `messages.js` from this path to your theme:
`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`

Into this folder of your theme:
 Magento_Theme/web/js/messages.js`

Now adapt the PHTML in your theme like so.

```
...
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
...
```

to:

```
...
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }, click: $parent.removeAll()">
...
```

Notice how we've added `click: $parent.removeAll()` to the `data-bind` attribute. This binds an event on the click on the message.

Now, inside `messages.js`, add the `removeAll` logic below the `prepareMessageForHtml` method, and don't forget about the comma (`,` after the function):

```
        removeAll: function() {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        }
```

Now, if you click the message, the message should disappear. This affects all visible messages, and can be styles with jQuery (which is a dependency for this JS file).