# Increase the success/exception message time span in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart

When a product adds to the cart the success/exception message is hiding rapidly, So I just tried the below way to show/increase the period of the message. But it's not worked for me.

I have modified the messages.js file as below from `vendor/magento/Module-Ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`

```
/**
         * @param {Boolean} isHidden
         */
        onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
            var self = this; 
            // Hide message block if needed
             if (isHidden) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(self.selector).hide('blind', {}, 500);
                }, 50000);
            }
        }
```

The above code is not working for me. Please suggest I increase the time of the message.

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256465/69 Be sure you're following the recommendation of NOT editing `vendor` directly. Use your own namespace/module to ensure your edits won't get overridden on updates. Also, be sure to clear both Magento's and Browser cache before testing.

Comment: https://www.interactiv4.com/blog-es-en/automatically-hide-messages-in-magento-2/?lang=en check this out

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282956/how-to-override-core-js-file-in-module

Comment: can you please share the file path where your putting your js?

Comment: weird. I tested adding to cart on clean magento 2.3.5. and the success message didn't hide...

Comment: @Pramod Modified the original `js` file i.e `vendor/magento/Module-Ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`

Comment: @SebastianT I'm also tested with Magento 2.3.3-p1 and it's showing the message not hiding, after applying the **Proto Smartwave** theme it's hiding after **1 sec**.

Comment: So the Proto Smartwave must somewhere create this functionality. Maybe it has custom module to do this.

Comment: Is there any demo version of this theme?

Comment: @SebastianT No,